Turned engine over wrong way now wont start
VW Polo 6r 2010
I was replacing the bearing on my air con compressor and took the fanbelt off and when i was putting it back on, i accidently turned the engine over the wrong way. I heard 3 clunks when i was doing it inside the engine and when i tried to start it it sounded really rough and like a diesel.  and now when i tried to turn it the correct way, i no longer could and felt huge resistance. I started the engine again and it did not start. everything turned over but nothing started. What should i do?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Hi thank you. It is a VW Polo 6r 2010.

I'm referring here to the timing belt, not the serpentine belt.
It's possible that if your timing belt tensioner is very weak and/or your timing belt has stretched beyond the recommended maximum length or if it was not changed when recommended, then it may have slipped a tooth. It's plausible that the three clunks that you heard correspond to slipping one tooth, three times.
Assuming that this is an interference engine, when you tried to turn it in the right direction and felt resistance, that was one of the pistons impinging on a valve at TDC.
You tried to start it and it "sounded like a diesel" so perhaps you were getting cylinder combustion with a valve not fully closed. You may have one or more bent valves now.
You may be able to learn more by taking off the valve cover and observing how the parts move as you rotate the engine in the right direction.
You may have a "teardown to inspect" in your future if you want to save this vehicle.

Thank you. I think you are correct as I also just got the DTC code P0341 which is crankshaft position sensor so i think the crankshaft has got out of time with the rest of the timing due to a loose timing chain tensioner which is a common problem in my car. I also think though, that when I started the engine the second time, it turned over (but did not start) with no horrid noises which suggests to me that the valves (hopefully) aren't bent. Anyway, have called the RAC to come and take it to a garage as it is out of my capabilities really. Thanks very much for your help!

Oh and also, do you know if 1 gear out is enough to bend my valves?

@WilliamD47 What I wrote about a timing belt would also apply to a timing chain. Is 1 tooth enough to bend a valve? I don't know, but if you could not turn the engine by hand, there was interference between piston and valve. Any interference can bend a valve. The fact that you can turn it now without interference is not necessarily a good sign: it could be that you eliminated interference by bending one or more valves and it won't start because you now have no compression because valves are stuck open.

@WilliamD47 For future reference, we usually wait 24 hours to accept an answer. This site has participants around the world, so waiting gives other time zones a chance to provide an answer that may be better.

Ah sorry about accepting too early. I had a look through the spark plug hole and couldnt see any loose metal so hopefully the valves are ok. RAC man has towed it down to a garage now which will take of the very complicated chain cover to have a look at the chain, tensioner and valves. Just before it's 150,000th mile as well! Thanks very much for your help again.
